# How do you show the recent Disqus comments feed?

Tags: comments

Does anyone know of a plugin to show the latest few Disqus comments that have been made across the entire site. Disqus seems to have deprecated their recent comments widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CX Disqus Comments](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cx-disqus-comments) and [Disqus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/disqus) both have the ability to sync/store native comments on your EE site. Once you have the Disqus comments synced into EE, you can use [comment tags](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/comment/index.html) to display recent comments across the entire site:

```
{exp:comment:entries sort="asc" limit="5" dynamic="no"}
        {comment}
        <p>By {name} on {comment_date format="%Y %m %d"}</p>
{/exp:comment:entries}
```

Comment: Both CX Comments and Disqus comments don't currently support oAuth so you would only be able to use either of those plugins if you have a legacy forum that allows you to authorize your app based upon your user credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I found that even though they don't provide the JS widget any more, they do still work.

https://gist.github.com/4174893

Answer (score 2):

You simply copy the following code where you want

```
<div id="recentcomments" class="dsq-widget"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourshortname.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=5&hide_avatars=0&avatar_size=32&excerpt_length=200"></script></div>
```

For more details check link : 
http://www.growtechinfo.com/2012/12/add-disqus-recent-comment-widget-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CX Disqus Comments](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cx-disqus-comments) and [Disqus](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/disqus). Disqus is free though CX Disqus Comments isn't. I'm not really sure if they do exactly what you're asking for but take a look.